# Setting up wordpress on a hosting server for the first time

Tags: multisite, installation

I'm moving a wordpress CMS installation from one host to another. Pretty straightforward I think. I have moved applications running on a Tomcat server but not wordpress. Is the following correct -

Restore the database from backup - Can I create a backup dump using wordpress admin GUI or do I need to manually restore on DB itself.

Would you recommend using the 5 minute install - http://wordpress.org/download/ ?
Once wordpress and the database is intalled on hosting site apply any theming to the CMS.
Are there any pitfalls I should watch out for ?

Am I on the right track ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just changing servers it's easiest just to move the entire installation over and clone the database (manually from db admin), then update wp-config.php to point to the correct database. If the domain name is changing you'll need to update all the domain name values in the database also. I find [this](http://interconnectit.com/124/search-and-replace-for-wordpress-databases/) script is the best way to do it - just make sure you keep a backup of the original. If it's for multisite I think you'll also need to update a setting in wp-config.php which contains domain name, have a look in that file to confirm...

Comment: When you say move do you mean just a "copy and paste" as specified in this tutorial ? - http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress#Moving_WordPress_to_a_New_Server

Comment: Yep. Just download everything and upload to the new server.